# How to add Language to Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, macos

I want to translate my app to another language. I've allready read [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) from Apple. Seems it's not working. A stuck when tried to add Russian language to Project. My actions:

1. Open Project settings.
2. Open Info pane.
3. Press plus under Localizations table
4. Choose Russian language
5. Press Finish in appearanced window

Result: no new language in Localizations table.

Project hasn't any .xib or .storyboard files. It has only Objective-C code without any forms.

Maybe I do all wrong. But I can't find good tutorial how do this in my case. So my case.

I have Xcode 10.1 Objective-C project for macOS. My app (plugin) must be translated to some languages. App hasn't any GUI. All text in `NSString`'s. Now I need to add translations for it. What workflow to do this? I need something simple

Comment: You are not telling Xcode which file you are going to localize.  Besides, Xcode is not going to make translation automatically for you.

Comment: I don't see when I can do this. How this can be done? I click right mouse button on my .m file in project explorer. No any Localize menu. Project Info pane also doesn't provide a way to choose my .m file.

Comment: Take a good look at the screenshot under the paragraph titled 'Verifying Your Steps' at the URL you have specified to see what they are localizing.  Nobody localizes .h or .m files.  Create a file named Localizable.strings.

Comment: It says *If you use NSLocalizedString macros in your code*. I have such in my code. But Xcode doesn't add Localizable.strings.

Comment: I suggest you run a search for Localizable.strings and read some topics.